# How do I use the new jQuery .on() function (with CoffeeScript)?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

`.on()` does not appear to function like `.live()`. All I want to do is a simple alert to get me going. I have the following element on my page:

```
<a class="add_showcase_item" href="javascript://">621015</a>
```

I have the following CoffeeScript:

```
$("a").live "click", ".add_showcase_item", ->
  alert "hello"
  false
```

Unfortunately, this causes the alert to go off on EVERY link. That doesn't make any sense I know. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/) say, you need to specify the delegate, and then as an argument you provide the actual selector you want to listen on:

```
$("body").on "click", "a.add_showcase_item" , -> //...
```

Comment: Specifying a delegate is optional, $('a.add_showcase_item').on will work as well

Comment: Technically you do. If you do not pass in a selector the delegate equals the listener. If you do however, the listener acts as delegate since the event targets are filtered.

Comment: Technically you don't, it's just a matter of performance (i don't argue over your proposed solution being the right one though)

Comment: I can tell you that the answer does work, but substituting "a.add_showcase_item" for "body" does NOT work. It should, but it definitely does not. I just find it silly that I am going to have to specify "body" for every .on() call. But I guess that's what I have to do.

Comment: You don't have to, he just used it as you didn't specify what container those links were in. So in your case $('#id_of_your_wrapper').on 'click', 'a.add_showcase_item' etc will work

Comment: @Metzger I appreciate your point. The way I understand it you should be able to substitute the proposed solution with `$("a.add_showcase_item").on "click", handler`. The latter just listens directly on the element itself.

Comment: Yes, you could, but as you stated, the optimal solution would be to delegate, as you don't want to monitor lots of links. Good times :)